# Using IIFEs in JS for protecting data by creating private variables

Tags: javascript, private, private-members, iife

I have created a small program to print some message in the console when a button in the DOM is clicked.

**Code-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onClick="printName()">Click</button>
</body>
<script>
    const personDetails = (function() {
        let name = 'john';
        function displayMsg() {
            console.log(name);
        }
        return {
            displayName: displayMsg
        }
    })();
    function printName() {
        personDetails.displayName(); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

In above code, to protect **name**, I am using IIFE and returning a method **displayName** inside **personDetails**. On click of button, **printName** is executed which further executes **personDetails.displayName**. Here are my concerns -

1. Is this the right way to use IIFEs to protect the data? **If no, then please provide a solution. This is getting confusing everyday.**
2. Even if we are keeping only 1 global variables, other exposed
   variables are accessible through the global one like **displayName**
   method.
3. Let's say I have successfully protected the data, still I am able to
   change the function definition in the console through
   **personDetails.displayName** which should be avoided.

   **Old method:**
   function displayMsg() { console.log(name); }

   **New method:**
   personDetails.displayName = function() { console.log('Hiiii'); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and visit the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**.

---

### 1. Is this the right way?

There is at least one 'close' vote for this question being primarily opinion-based.  That voter is correct that this portion of the question is hard to answer definitively.

So let me just say that this is at least *one appropriate way* to do this.  There are many others.  You could simplify this, if you like, to

```
const personDetails = (function() {
  let name = 'john';
  return {
    displayName: function() {
      console.log(name);
    }
  }
})()
```

And you could simplify it still more by using arrow functions.

### 2. Why are other variables still exposed?

That is the point of such code: to create a public interface that makes reference to some private data.  You could also skip `personDetails` and expose only `displayName` by returning the function and not an object with that function as a property.

But if you want to be able to use that data, then you need at least some public interface!

### 3. How is it that this function reference can still be changed?

There are **[techniques](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)** that would allow you to protect this variable from change.  But then, perhaps, a user will redefine `personDetails` to be something else.  Could you protect this?  Maybe.  But then what's to stop someone from intercepting your Javascript before it's interpreted by the browser, altering these definitions?

The point is that you will only ever have so much control.  If you don't trust users, you shouldn't be shipping them code... which means you shouldn't be writing for the web.

Using IIFEs to protect data from accidental changes, or even well-meaning but dangerous intentional changes, is fine.  Trying to pretend that you're entirely in charge of the code once it leaves your hands is folly however.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Yes, but there is only **one** global variable. This massively reduces the risk of other code *accidentally* overwriting it.
3. Yes. You can't stop deliberate modification to code once it has left your control and arrived at the client.

Minimising use of globals is a strategy to reduce the likelihood of bugs caused by other code. It isn't a form of DRM.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have successfully protected the data, still I am able to
>   change the function definition in the console through
>   personDetails.displayName which should be avoided.

This can be avoided by changing the value of the `writable` property of the returned object.

Modify the function assignment of `personDetails` as follows:

```
"use strict";
const personDetails = (function() {
    let name = 'john';
    function displayMsg() {
        console.log(name);
    }
    var obj = {};
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'displayName', {
        value: displayMsg,
        writable: false
    });

    return obj;
})();
```

Now, if anyone tries to overwrite the property value,

```
function printName() {
    personDetails.displayName = 10; 
}
printName();
```

you get an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'displayName' of object '#<Object>'
    at printName (<anonymous>:17:35)
```

Check out [this writeup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more details.

**Note:** This will throw an error only in strict mode and silently reject any change otherwise.